# RETR command in FTP, how does the server send a file to the client?

Tags: sockets, ftp, client-server, protocols

I'm implementing a very simple FTP server program that is able to retrieve and store text files. my question is, when a ftp client request say a file with the following "RETR test.txt" how does the server send this file?. Does it open that text file copy the contents into a buffer and simply send it or is there more to it?. I'm not sure how to implement this, could someone clarify the basic idea?.

**edit::**

```
if (strncmp(receive_buffer,"RETR",4)==0)  {
                sprintf(send_buffer,"150 Opening ASCII mode data connection... \r\n");
                printf("<< DEBUG INFO. >>: REPLY sent to CLIENT: %s\n", send_buffer);
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                if (bytes < 0) break;
                closesocket(ns);

                char temp_buffer2[80];

                FILE *fin=fopen("test.txt","r");//open test.txt
                while (!feof(fin)){
                    fgets(temp_buffer2,78,fin);
                    sprintf(send_buffer,"%s",temp_buffer2);
                    printf("%s",send_buffer);

                    if (active==0) {
                        printf("***active is 0");
                        send(ns_data, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("***active is 1+");
                        send(s_data_act, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                    }
                }
                fclose(fin);
                sprintf(send_buffer,"226 File transfer complete. \r\n");
                printf("<< DEBUG INFO. >>: REPLY sent to CLIENT: %s\n", send_buffer);
                bytes = send(ns, send_buffer, strlen(send_buffer), 0);
                if (active==0 )closesocket(ns_data);
                else closesocket(s_data_act);
            }
```

this is what I have done, and for the RETR command it opens test.txt to try and send it. But this causes the server to disconnect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One bug in your code is that you are calling `closesocket(ns)` to disconnect the client's command connection after sending the intial reply, before sending the file over the data connection.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt matter how you send it. You can read one byte at a time and call `Send` for each byte. Or you could create a buffer of 8192 bytes and send that much at a time. Or any other number of bytes.

What do matter is if the FTP server is in active or passive mode: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: hello, the server is in active mode, but how do I send a file like that?

Comment: then buy or use an open source component instead. It sounds cheaper.

Comment: well. You are using passive mode in your code.. Active mode means that transfers are done in seperate connections.

Comment: but a PORT command is being issued by the client and the server flags that using the "active" variable

Comment: yes `s_data_act`. And I'm getting a positive response from the server when listening in active mode. but the ftp client never gets the file and the server just disconnects?. is the way I'm sending the file correct?. I'm just reading the text inside the file into a buffer and sending it??.

Comment: no need to put it in a buffer first. I would use binary mode for all file transfers. File read example: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-howto-read-binary-file-into-buffer-172985/. Just include the socket `send` in the loop.

Comment: @jgauffin: both ACTIVE and PASSIVE transfer are done over a separate connection.